# How to filter checkbox names with search bar in Element UI - Vue.js

Tags: javascript, vue.js, element-ui, element-plus

I have multiple checkboxes bottom of a search button and I want to display a spesific checkbox when user enters its name. For instance:

[sample image of search bar and checkbox](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ISRDX.png)

As shown in the image, when user enters "Positive", other checkboxes must be hidden and only "Positive" must be shown.

I have tried giving ref to checkboxes and filter input parameter inside of watch method but could not get the result. Here is my relating code:

Search bar:

```
                <el-input v-model="searchLabelFilters" class="chart-search-tab" placeholder="Search" />
```

Sample checkbox:

```
                <el-checkbox
                    ref="checkBoxRef"
                    v-model="checkedCheckBox1"
                    label="Positive"
                    size="large"
                    id="0"
                    @change="filterList('positive')"
                />
```

Mounted and watch methods:

```
                  mounted() {
                   this.checkBoxRef = this.$refs.checkBoxRef;
                  },
                  watch: {
                    searchLabelFilters() {
                    this.checkBoxRef.filter(this.searchLabelFilters);
                  },
                  },
```

Comment: The reference points to an html element. This.checkboxRef.filter is a non existing function on an HTML element.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. Do you have any other suggestion on what I am trying to do?

Comment: How are your options defined? Is it directly in the html template?

Comment: All of my options defined in script part with TS. HTML part consists similar of the code that I added above.

Comment: Do you use a v-for to render the different checkboxes (based on your options defined in script)?